# How to import PKCS#8 RSA privateKey (created by OpenSSL) in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, private-key, pkcs#8

I'm trying to find a way to read a privateKey created using OpenSSL PKCS#8 RSA in C# without use external library.

Does Someone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this *with* an external library, is using the (free) [Chillkat Public / Private Key Component](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/privatekey-features.asp): using that, importing the key can be done using [just a few lines of code](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/rsa_signPkcs8.asp) and if you're willing to pay the $149 or so for the rest of the library, it will make dealing with general crypto concepts a lot easier as well.

And unlike the regular Microsoft .NET Framework, the Mono project *does* seem to have a [PKCS8 implementation](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=18@ecma%3a349%23PKCS8%2f) for which the [full C# source](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid0005D522A9B5E25FEF70E4D9DA37822E5E9725EC.aspx) is available. This may be suitable as a starting point in case you absolutely cannot rely on external libraries, assuming the (LGPL 2.0) license associated with the Mono code works for you...

Finally, the [PKCS #8 format](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/doc/pkcs-8.doc) is not too difficult to parse, and the RSA/DSA key pair objects are as per [PKCS #11](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-30/pkcs-11v2-30m1-d7.pdf) and relatively easy to convert to a .NET X509Certificate once you figure out where all the bits go -- I actually did this in VB.NET a while ago, but unfortunately am not able to share that code.

Comment: I need something free and Opensource. But thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sure its easy to do, but i don't want to do it. Thats why i got that library. Simple, opensource and free.

Answer (score 5):

As of .Net Core 3:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

// ...

// I had my PK in base64
var pkBase64 = "MIIEvQI...";

var rsa = RSA.Create(); 
rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(pkBase64), out _);
```

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importpkcs8privatekey?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hi, is there any solution for .Net Core 2?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

My script to create RSA key i used OpenSSL whit:

(Linux Script)

```
openssl genrsa -out ${NAME}_openssl.key 2048
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in ${NAME}_openssl.key -nocrypt > ${NAME}.key
openssl req -new -x509 -key ${NAME}.key -out ${NAME}.crt -outform DER
```

In C# we need privateKey in XML format. I used [this](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/index.html) parser to do this.

To decrypt de challenge we need to use:

```
  byte[] challange = server.getChallenge();

  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

  rsaProvider.FromXmlString(Demo.Properties.Resources.XmlPrivateKey);

  byte[] plaintext = rsaProvider.Decrypt(challange, false);
```

To encrypt whit server certificate we need to use:

```
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = x509.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

  byte[] answer = RsaProvider.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
```

Thanks for JavaScience Consulting

Comment: The question was how to import PKCS#8, not the kay as XML file