# How can I add a private key to X509Certificate2 after I have already added the public key?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, rsa, x509

My steps are:

1. Create `X509Certificate2` with public key:

   ```
   X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("public key certificate blob as byte[]");
   ```
2. How do I want to load the private key blob to `clientCertificate`?

Comment: What kind of blobs do you have? Where they come from?

Comment: Does it metter? My public key is string in Base64 format. I convert this string to Byte array. The private key is the asymmetric key of the public key. The private key is in the same format as the public key (Base64) and i like to add it to my X509Certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can not import RSA private key with just .net framework tools.

Check out this thread [How to read a PEM RSA private key from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net).

Comment: Doesn't work... I guess the key is not RSACryptoServiceProvider. I need a general solution for this issue. My issue is - I am working with WLAN configuration, when my user configure wireless profile, he gives me public key in one file, and private key in another.

Comment: BTW - The certificate is RSA certificate. but when i am executing the next line - csp.ImportCspBlob(privateKeyBlob); , i am getting an exception... :(

Comment: Can you post it? And what file format  is used as private key container?

Comment: I can't post the private key :(.

Comment: Oh, no! I mean exception text! You wrote: "but when i am executing the next line - csp.ImportCspBlob(privateKeyBlob); , i am getting an exception... :(". Can you post Exception details?

Comment: {System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Version of provider.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportCspBlob(Byte[] keyBlob, SafeProvHandle hProv, CspProviderFlags flags, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.ImportCspBlobHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, Byte[] keyBlob, Boolean publicOnly, CspParameters& parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
....

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone like me and up looking at this old post when searching for how to generate X509Certificate2 from pem fil/private key:

The .Net 5.0 framework has a very simplified approach to this:

```
var certPem = File.ReadAllText("cert.pem");
var eccPem = File.ReadAllText("ecc.pem");
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(certPem, eccPem);
```

(source: https://www.scottbrady91.com/C-Sharp/PEM-Loading-in-dotnet-core-and-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

Also see: [How to import PKCS#8 RSA privateKey (created by OpenSSL) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722305/how-to-import-pkcs8-rsa-privatekey-created-by-openssl-in-c-sharp)

It includes a link to Mono's source code which can read PKCS#8 / PEM files and return an `RSA` instance from it.