# Import of Pkcs#8 encrypted private key using .NET

Tags: c#, import, private-key, pkcs#8

I want to import (RSA and ECDsa) private keys from pkcs8 files (-----BEGIN **ENCRYPTED** PRIVATE KEY-----).

This question [How to import PKCS#8 RSA privateKey (created by OpenSSL) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722305/how-to-import-pkcs8-rsa-privatekey-created-by-openssl-in-c-sharp) has been answered, but the only acceptable solution for me is to implement pkcs8 parser which I want to avoid to as well as using of 3rd party libraries (beside the Chillkat there is also BouncyCastle and its PemReader) as well as pinvoke and `NCryptImportKey` (mentioned here: [Importing PKCS#8 encrypted key to RSACng?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561155/importing-pkcs8-encrypted-key-to-rsacng)) (I didn't go this way so far, so I'm not sure it is suitable. Is it?).

I would expect something like `CngKey key = CngKey.Import(bytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob, password)` unfortunately `Import` method supports import of unencrypted keys only (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----).

Is there any other way to get those keys using .NET version: 4.7.2?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The question and answer from the second of your links is from only a few months ago. Are expecting something to have changed since then?

Comment: @JamesKPolk: second link/QA solves RSA only. I need ECDsa as well. Change or new information would be great as well.  
Meanwhile I found out that ECDsa key is imported as ECDH via CngKey.Import(..) which is quite useless for me as I need it to recreate X509Certificate2 (the file contains both key and certificate)

Comment: `NCryptImportKey` is the way to go, but the code isn't really pleasant.  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/64477348da1ff57a43deb65a4b12d32986ed00bd/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng/src/System/Security/Cryptography/CngKey.Import.cs#L49-L100 is an example of this in .NET Core 3.0 (for the DER/binary form, no idea if NCryptImport does PEM parsing), if you want to try to use it as a guide; but it's pretty messy.  Or, you could try [.NET Core Daily Builds](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/daily-builds.md) and preview the feature.