# C# BouncyCastle PKCS#8

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, ecdsa, pkcs#8

I want load the PEM using .net framework (not .netcore)

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIHs........................................................CAAw
DAYI........................................................gZAf
Y/Iu........................................................X7DZ
ZKoE........................................................OYQQ
3ZST........................................................A2E=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

- I tried to use the following code using BouncyCastle, but it throw PemException:
  "problem creating ENCRYPTED private key: Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted"

```
 class Passowrd : IPasswordFinder
    {
        private string v;

        public Passowrd(string v)
        {
            this.v = v;
        }

        public char[] GetPassword()
        {
            return v.ToCharArray();
        }
    }

var pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(privateKeyText), new Passowrd("PASSWORD"));
var pemObj = pemReader.ReadObject(); // this line throw PemException
```

- However, I load the exact same PEM file using .netcore3.1 by the following code:

```
    var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
    ecdsa.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(passSpan, privateKeyBytes, out _);
```

Comment: Mmmh, I can't reproduce the issue on _.NET Framework 4.7.2_. This error message is e.g. displayed if the password is incorrect or if the `IPasswordFinder` implementation is buggy. Please post your `Passowrd`-Implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added the password implementation.

Comment: The code works for me (.NET Framework 4.7.2). Possibly a typo in the password? Which .NET Framework version are you using?

Comment: the password is correct for sure, I'm using the exact same password in the .netcore code and it works.
what is the version of "bouncy-castle" which do you use?
I'm using
<package id="BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="net472" />

Comment: I'm using 1.8.5. If the password for the posted key is really PASSWORD, then I can reproduce the issue. Then there seems to be an issue with this particular key, because with other keys it works. I'll have a look at the key.

Comment: For your key/password I can reproduce the issue. For other keys it works. How was your key generated?

Comment: it was generated from python and I'm using it as a client.
I think it happen because the key was generated by ecdsa.

Comment: Never post any secret information on stackoverflow, such as a private key, unless it just an example and not in real use.

Comment: yes it's for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the PEM either using

```
var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(new StringReader(privateKeyText), new Passowrd("PASSWORD"));
```

or

```
var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader(new StringReader(privateKeyText));
```

then read content like

```
var pemObject = pemReader.ReadPemObject();
```

Comment: But ReadPemObject doesn't return the KeyPair....

in other words, I want:

            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair KeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemObject .ReadObject();

Comment: similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987169/import-of-pkcs8-encrypted-private-key-using-net/61245450#61245450

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the encryption of the key: The key cannot be read with the `PemReader` if the option `-v2prf hmacWithSHA1` is not set when the key is encrypted.

The option [`-v2prf`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs8.html) exists since V1.1.0 and specifies the PRF (pseudo-random function) algorithm used with [PKCS#5 v2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) or the key derivation function [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

- Case 1: Creating a new key

The following two statements create and encrypt the key:

```
    openssl ecparam -name secp256r1 -genkey -noout -out <out-path>
    openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 aes256 -v2prf hmacWithSHA1 -in <in-path> -out <out-path>  // aes256 as of OpenSSL 1.1.0 inclusive
```

A key generated in this way can be successfully read with the `PemReader`. However, if the option `-v2prf hmacWithSHA1` is missing, the exception is thrown.

- Case 2: Fixing an already generated key

The following statement decrypts an already encrypted key:

```
    openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in <in-path> -out <out-path>
```

If the key is subsequently encrypted with the `-v2prf hmacWithSHA1` option set (see above), the key can be read successfully with the `PemReader`. *This way I was able to fix the posted key so that it could be read with the `PemReader`!*

A possible (unfortunately only superficial) explanation can be found in the documentation of `openssl pkcs8`. There it can be read about the [`-v2prf`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs8.html) option:

> Some implementations may not support custom PRF algorithms and may require the hmacWithSHA1 option to work.

Interestingly, the critical keys can be read without problems using `ECDsa#ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey` from .NET Core 3.x. For a complete explanation a look into the source code would probably be necessary.